# How to copy a preceding sibling that has given name?

Tags: xslt

Given something like this:

```
<source>
 <somestuff>
  <thead>
   <row>C1</row>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <row>C2</row>
  <row>C3</row>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
 <somestuff>
  <tbody>
   <row>C4</row>
   <row>C5</row>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
 <somestuff>
  <tbody>
   <row>C6</row>
   <row>C7</row>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
</source>
```

I need to copy the contents of the thead element as first child to the following tbody element. (There could be any number of thead elements.) Resulting in:

```
<source>
 <somestuff>
  <tbody>
  <row>C1</row>
  <row>C2</row>
  <row>C3</row>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
 <somestuff>
  <tbody>
   <row>C4</row>
   <row>C5</row>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
 <somestuff>
  <tbody>
   <row>C6</row>
   <row>C7</row>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
</source>
```

I tried this

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity" >
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbody/*[1]">
 <xsl:copy-of select=
     "preceding-sibling::*[1]
                      [name()='thead']/row"/>
<xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>


<!-- deleting the Head node  -->
 <xsl:template match="//thead"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but failed. Thank you. Ralf

Comment: How exactly did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity" >
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="tbody/*[1]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::thead[1]/node()" />
  <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- deleting the Head node  -->
 <xsl:template match="thead"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key problem with your original stylesheet is that you're trying to select

```
preceding-sibling::*[1][name()='thead']
```

when the context node is a *child* of `tbody`, not `tbody` itself.  My version adds a `..` to get up to the `tbody` before looking for its `preceding-sibling::thead[1]`.

Note that this does not cover the case where you have an empty `tbody` or a `thead` with no following `tbody`.  To catch those cases you might be better off templating the `thead` instead

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity" >
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- ignore a tbody that immediately follows a thead -->
 <xsl:template match="tbody[preceding-sibling::*[1]/self::thead]"/>

 <xsl:template match="thead">
  <tbody>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]/self::tbody/node()" />
  </tbody>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the same result on your original XML but can also cope with things like

```
 <somestuff>
  <thead>
   <row>C9</row>
  </thead>
 </somestuff>
```

or

```
 <somestuff>
  <thead>
   <row>C9</row>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </somestuff>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. If there is a thead there will always be a tbody. But I will try your second suggestion. First one works.

Comment: @user2062242 Glad it helped, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you get an answer that solves your problem it's good manners to _accept_ it by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer.  If you build a track record of accepting good answers it will make people more likely to help you with your future questions.